# hibernate Mapping One to many relation ship between primary key and composite key

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I am struggling with a hibernate mapping problem of mapping One to many relation ship between Primary key of Order Table and composite key of Product Cart with some extra columns

```
public class OrderDetails implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="ORDERID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer orderId;

@Column(name="ORDER_DATE")
private Date orderDate= new Date();
//other fields and getter setter
.....
.....
```

Product Cart table has a composite key CART ID and PRODUCT ID

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCT_CART")
@AssociationOverrides({
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.shopCart", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="CARTID")),
    @AssociationOverride(name="pk.product", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PRODUCTID"))
})
public class ProductCart implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ProductCartId pk = new ProductCartId();

@Column(name="QUANTITY")
private Integer selectedQuantity=1;

@Column(name="TOTAL")
private double total=0.0;
//other fields and getter setter
.....
.....
```

I tried following but not working

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PRODUCTCART_ORDERDETAILS")
@AssociationOverrides({
@AssociationOverride(name="pcoPK.orderDetails",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ORDERID"))    ,
@AssociationOverride(name="pcoPK.pk", joinColumns=       
    {@JoinColumn(name="pk.shopCart",referencedColumnName="CARTID"),
    @JoinColumn(name="pk.product",referencedColumnName="PRODUCTID") }) })

public class ProductCartOrder implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2348674131019001487L;

@EmbeddedId
private ProductCartOrderId pcoPK = new ProductCartOrderId();

@Column(name="QUANTITY")
private Integer quantity;

@Column(name="PRICE")
private double price;

@Transient
public OrderDetails getOrderDetails(){
    return getPcoPK().getOrderDetails();
}
public void setOrderDetails(OrderDetails orderDetails){
    getPcoPK().setOrderDetails(orderDetails);
}

@Transient
public ProductCartId getProductCartId(){
    return getPcoPK().getPk();
}
public void setProductCartId(ProductCartId pk){
getPcoPK().setPk(pk);
}
```

Can someone please help me to implement this? Below is the error message

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to define a @JoinColumn with a mappedBy association: pcoPK.pk
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.buildJoinColumn(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.buildJoinColumns(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1212)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.fillComponent(AnnotationBinder.java:1841)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindId(AnnotationBinder.java:1878)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of research I could not find the solution I done it in another way. 
I created Many to many relationship between OrderDetails and Product with some extra columns ID, price, quantity and inserted value manually for each element in product cart thorugh a for loop.

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
private Set<ProductOrder> productOrder;
...//other fields and getter setter
}

public class OrderDetails implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(mappedBy="orderDetails")
private Set<ProductOrder> productOrder;
...//other fields and getter setter
}

public class ProductOrder {

@Id
@Column(name="PRODUCT_ORDER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int prductOrderId;

@ManyToOne
private OrderDetails orderDetails;

@ManyToOne
private Product product;
...//other fields and getter setter
}
```

In my controller class where I wanted to save the products of ProductCart I did following

```
List<ProductCart> productList = new ArrayList<ProductCart>();
    productList=productCartService.getCartProducts(shopCart);

    ProductOrder orderedProducts = new ProductOrder();

    for (ProductCart productCarts : productList) {
        orderedProducts.setOrderDetails(orderDetails);
        orderedProducts.setProduct(productCarts.getPk().getProduct());
        orderedProducts.setPrice(productCarts.getPk().getProduct().getPrice());
        orderedProducts.setQuantity(productCarts.getSelectedQuantity());
        productOrderService.addOrderProducts(orderedProducts);
        }
```